# mysqli_field_type returns a number

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I call mysqli_field_type it returns a number, which I assume relates to the type. Does anyone have a list of types and their corresponding numbers? 
I am in particular trying to find out if the data type is numerical or text (if that makes a difference).

Comment: Uhm... I did not find that function in the PHP manual. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: mysqli_field_type()? According to the manual, there is no such function.

Comment: What number is returned exactly? I mean, if the function doesn't exist, it seems odd that you get an integer back.

Comment: I also can not find it in there... However I do get a result that definately relates to the type (the fields with the same data type return the same number). They use it here - http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Implementing-Additional-Methods-with-mysqli-and-PHP-5/3/

Comment: @Franz an integer field returns 3, Varchar is 253 and 246 is decimal

Comment: I guess I could go on and get each data type... be much easier with a list mind

Comment: I found the function - http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.mysqli-fetch-field.php

Answer (score 0):

Can be useful to someone, use this function:

```
$type = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->type;
```

Find out more: [result->fetch_field_direct](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: mysqli_field_type: this function does not exist, so I can not provide an answer to a question from a function that does not exist in PHP. 
"This extension has been deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7.0.0."
However I found it interesting to inform the correct function in PHP 7.0.0.